# logs for user activity in vba userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I am trying to work on a code that will give me the user activity on the userform that I have created. I want to keep this logs file in shared drive if possible.
 below is my code, not getting any records in logs folder

```
Sub LogInformation(LogMessage As String)

    Const LogFileName As String = "D:\FOLDERNAME\TEXTFILE.LOG"

    Dim FileNum As Integer

    FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number

    Open LogFileName For Append As #FileNum ' creates the file if it doesn't exist

    Print #FileNum, LogMessage ' write information at the end of the text file

    Close #FileNum ' close the file

End Sub


Public Sub DisplayLastLogInformation()

    Const LogFileName As String = "D:\FOLDERNAME\TEXTFILE.LOG"

    Dim FileNum As Integer, tLine As String

    FileNum = FreeFile ' next file number

    Open LogFileName For Input Access Read Shared As #f ' open the file for reading

    Do While Not EOF(FileNum)

        Line Input #FileNum, tLine ' read a line from the text file

    Loop ' until the last line is read

    Close #FileNum ' close the file

    MsgBox tLine, vbInformation, "Last log information:"

End Sub


Sub DeleteLogFile(FullFileName As String)

    On Error Resume Next ' ignore possible errors

    Kill FullFileName ' delete the file if it exists and it is possible

    On Error GoTo 0 ' break on errors

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    LogInformation ThisWorkbook.Name &amp; " opened by " &amp; _

    Application.UserName &amp; " " &amp; Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have created a userform of login page ... once user is logged in I have anothe userform to connect to database. .....Now I want to generate a log file having user activity ..who has loggedin to userform what changes have been done.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What is your question?

Comment: I believe his question is "Why am I not getting any records in logs folder?"

Comment: yes,or if you can suggest your code that is working

Comment: if you run the workbook.open event using F8 what value does the statement 

ThisWorkbook.Name &amp; " opened by " &amp; _

    Application.UserName &amp; " " &amp; Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")  have?

Comment: I just tested your code as is (assuming the `amp;` is just mark-up, i removed that) and it worked perfect. Appended the text to the log file each time I ran it. Are you sure `"D:\FOLDERNAME\TEXTFILE.LOG"` is a valid **shared drive**? (D:\ is typically used for a person's local folder (in my experience).